# How to make it to set the lxappearance cursor with the start of qtile?

Tags: archlinux

I use qtile on arch linux and when I set the cursor in lxappearance, it all works fine but after a reboot the cursor is set to default. Then I have to launch lxappearance again to change it. How do I make it to set the cursor with the start of qtile?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for a long time. Just copy your cursor folder from `~/.local/share/icons/` to `~/.icons/`.

Comment: Well, I tried it and it didn't work. Also, I found out that the cursor doesn't reset only after a reboot, it resets after every qtile restart.

Comment: Weird =/ . I happened to see ur question when searching for an answer. For me, just copying and rebooting had it done.